# Can you dual boot two operating systems on seperate disks and one is removable?

Tags: windows-10, debian, multi-boot, dualboot

I want to dual-boot with Linux (Debian) being my primary operating system on internal SSD and Windows 10 on an separate external SSD as my secondary, because my laptop has only one disk storage slot.

**Question:**
Is there a way to dual boot in such way so that the operating system on external disk can be removable?

By removable I mean when I would need Windows I would plug my SSD into a laptop and boot into it and when I won't be using Windows I could boot into Linux with second external disk not being present or plugged in.

I know its possible to dual boot two operating systems on two separate disks but they have to be connected at all times. Because I need my laptop to be portable for collage I can't have second SSD constantly hanging out of my usb-c port.
I also don't want to partition one disk because there is a possibility that one operating system writes over a part of second partition. If the disks are physically separate there is less/none chance of this happening.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: If you are setting up the Dual boot correctly there is no risk of anything writing over the other, and even when there is, it's only about overwriting the boot (and not the OS itself) which you can fix. To your question, it's possible to boot from an external drive (and simply have the boot order set to boot from the external first if present) but you can't boot Windows from an external, so perhaps do the Debian on the external and Windows on the internal.

Comment: Short answer is yes, as long as you configure it properly. As commented above Linux is a lot more forgiving when installed in an external drive. That said, if you know what you're doing you can have the ESP in the internal drive and the system partition of whatever OS you choose in another drive with the only caveat the externally installed OS won't be portable. Unfortunately whenever someone asks this kind of question that person is unlikely to be capable of pulling it out.